# What's the point of day-and-night cycle?

Tags: far-cry-6

In Far Cry 6, there is a day and night cycle, lasting about 20 minutes each.

I know some missions can only be done during the night, and as far as I have noticed, it will influence some NPCs activities like villagers getting to their work spot. (By NPCs, I mean those Dani can't interact with, not the sellers, etc.)

But gameplay-wise, is there a difference between playing during the day and during the night? Is Dani easier to spot by the FND during the day, is it easier to go stealth during the night? Etc.